# go regex parsing string to environment variable

Tags: regex, go

I have a string that I am trying parse using [go regexp](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) and convert to `os.Getenv(env)`. Assuming we have string `"hello world -p $PATH -f $HOSTNAME "` in Go, and want to use regexp to read `os.Getenv("PATH")` and `os.Getenv("HOSTNAME")`. Anyone can help me with a proper regexp parser that will extract out `"$"` along with the word pass it through the `os.Getenv()` as the parameter for getting the environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [os.ExpandEnv](http://godoc.org/os#ExpandEnv) function replaces $var or ${var} in a string according to the values in the environment. I recommend using this function instead of writing your own using regular expressions.

Comment: This is a bit odd because it only replaces a single pattern at a time.  I would expect a use of ReplaceAllFunc() instead.  Example: http://play.golang.org/p/fdAqs-Rdlo